# htaccess redirect to different domains if url contains word

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a website that I'm splitting into two. So I want to redirect all pages to one of two other domains depending on whether the url contains a particular keyword. So something like that below in .htaccess:

```
if ("keyword" is in the url) site A redirects to site B
else site A redirects to site C
```

Comment: Hi, was my answer useful? Maybe if you provide more information I could lend you another hand.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some rules I use in a case like yours, it works fine. Hope this helps

```
RewriteCond   %{HTTP_HOST}               www\.oldhost\.com
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_URI}             ^/yourkeyword/.*
RewriteRule   ^/yourkeyword/(.*)         http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ("keyword" is in the url) site A redirects to site B
else site A redirects to site C
```

This can be translated into these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?oldsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule keyword http://www.siteA.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?oldsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.siteB.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```